# "No matching configuration of project :entitymodel was found" when Declaring Dependencies between projects with Gradle Kotlin Springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, gradle, dependencies

I have 2 springboot projects, entitymodel and onboarding. I want the project onboarding to use what was coded in entitymodel project. So my entitymodel build.gradle.kts is like this:

```
import org.gradle.api.publish.PublishingExtension

plugins {
    `java-library`
    `maven-publish`
    //signing

    id("org.springframework.boot") version "3.1.1"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.1.0"
}


group = "com.restaurant"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.projectlombok:lombok")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    runtimeOnly("org.postgresql:postgresql")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}


configure<PublishingExtension> {
    publications.create<MavenPublication>("entitymodel") {
        groupId = "com.restaurant"
        artifactId = "entitymodel"
        version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
        pom.packaging = "jar"
        artifact("$buildDir/libs/entitymodel-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-plain.jar")

    }
    repositories {
        maven {
            name = "archiva"
            url = uri("http://localhost:8082/repository/internal/")
            isAllowInsecureProtocol = true
            credentials {
                username = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
                password = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and my onboarding build.gradle.kts and settings.gradle.kts are like this:

```
plugins {
    java
    war
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "3.1.2"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.1.2"
}

group = "com.restaurant"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        name = "archiva"
        url = uri("http://localhost:8082/repository/internal/")
        isAllowInsecureProtocol = true
        credentials {
            username = "aaaaaaaaaaaaa"
            password = "aaaaaaaaaaaaa"
        }
    }

}

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.cacheDynamicVersionsFor(1, "minutes")
    resolutionStrategy.cacheChangingModulesFor(1, "minutes")
}




dependencies {
    implementation("org.projectlombok:lombok")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat")
    //implementation("com.restaurant:entitymodel:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT")
    implementation(project(":entitymodel"))
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    developmentOnly("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")
    developmentOnly("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.restdocs:spring-restdocs-mockmvc")
    runtimeOnly("org.postgresql:postgresql")
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

```
rootProject.name = "onboarding"
include(":entitymodel")
```

but when I run ./gradlew clean build on the onboarding project, I receive this:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':bootWar'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':runtimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve project :entitymodel.
     Required by:
         project :
      > No matching configuration of project :entitymodel was found. The consumer was configured to find a library for use during runtime, compatible with Java 17, packaged as a jar, preferably optimized for standard JVMs, and its dependencies declared externally but:
          - None of the consumable configurations have attributes.
```

what am I missing?

I coded looking at these two Gradle documentations:
[Dependencies between projects](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_dependencies.html#sub:project_dependencies)
[Declaring Dependencies between Subprojects](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_dependencies_between_subprojects.html)

and searched into some forums to solve this issue but couldn't find out the problem yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your `settings.gradle.kts`, it looks like you are trying to make a root project depend on its subproject. Instead, put `onboarding` as a subproject too. The `settings.gradle.kts` should be:

```gradle
rootProject.name = "anything-else"

include("entitymodel")
include("onboarding")
```

and its folder structure:

```
.
├── entitymodel
│   └── build.gradle.kts
├── onboarding
│   └── build.gradle.kts
└── settings.gradle.kts
```

To generate a working example quickly, you can run command `gradle init` in any empty folder, and enter `yes` when it asks you whether to generate multiple subprojects.

#### References

- https://docs.gradle.org/8.2.1/userguide/multi_project_builds.html

Comment: I created a gradle project called Restaurant in the directory that entitymodel and onboarding are, imported both inside Restaurant settings.gradle.kts: 
`rootProject.name = "restaurant"
include("entitymodel")
include("onboarding")`
and left the Restaurant build.gradle.kts blank, because in this case, I want one subproject to be a dependency of the other.  when I tried to build my onboarding build.gradle.kt I received the same error.

Comment: So what u need to do is to remove the settings.gradle.kts inside onboarding.

Comment: Ok! when I removed both settings of the subprojects it worked! thanks @chehsunliu

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `implementation project(':entitymodel')` instead of `implementation(project(":entitymodel"))` and `include("entitymodel")` instead of `include(":entitymodel")`?